# Create job in jenkins with calling svn and maven

Tags: maven, svn, build, jenkins

For now I have a batch file with commands for update projects using svn and calling maven 'clean install'. How to create some job in Jenkins for similar actions?
Should I write it to ant file (sorry if it's stupid idea, I've just heard about it but I don't  know what is it exactly and what can I do with this) or there is other way?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at Jenkins? Jenkins will handle the checkout in SVN for you. Jenkins will handle the build with Maven for you. All you need to do is to specify in Jenkins what you want to do. Install Jenkins and take a look. Download Jenkins and install it. Jenkins is simple to setup. Once you have done that and explored Jenkins a bit, you can ask a specific question on how you can do something in Jenkins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like arghtype suggested, you need to be using Jenkin's own Source Code Management by configuring SVN as SCM source and supplying credentials as part of Maven build job.

If you **have** to use your own local working copy, you are organizing it wrong, you will lose on all the benefits of having Jenkins manage SVN changes, and in the end, this organization will give you more unsolvable problems in the future. Think about the advice people are giving here and come with up a reason *why* you need to have a local workspace outside of Jenkins management on a Jenkins build machine. My only guess is: your Jenkins and Development machine are the same. That again is not how it should be organized. Jenkins is a CI-server, not a personal build "automator".

Regardless, if you still want to do what you say.

**What you think you want**

- Create a new **Freestyle** job
- Under **Build Steps**, click **Add build step**
- Select **Execute Windows batch command**
- Write your batch execute command in there. Your working directory will be Jenkins's `$WORKSPACE`, so change your path accordingly to where you want to run it.

But with the above configuration, you might have as well put the batch file under windows scheduler... You are not really using Jenkins with the above.

**What you should do instead**

- Create a new **maven2/3** build job
- Under **Source Code Management**, select **Subversion**
- Under **Repository URL** enter the remote SVN repo (i.e. `http://your.svnsever.com/path/to/project`)
- Under **Build**, enter your **Root POM** location (this will be relative to the location of your SVN checkout, so if your POM is under `http://your.svnserver.com/path/to/project/maven/pom.xml`, then enter `maven/pom.xml`.
- Under **Goals and options**, enter `clean install`
- Click **Save**

The *Source Code Management* section will take care of setting up a local workspace and checkout the repository into that workspace. By default, every time a new build is triggered, it will run `svn update` on that workspace for you.

The *Maven Build* step will take care of running your Maven, however note that it is configured to use default `~/.m2/repository` location. If your local maven repo needs to be different, change this under Jenkins Global Configuration

Comment: Even if it works and seems obviously, I wanted to tell you that some guys say that: 'Jenkins' Maven job type considered evil'. [Here's why](http://javaadventure.blogspot.ch/2013/11/jenkins-maven-job-type-considered-evil.html).

Comment: @danny After years of working with Jenkins, I will agree with you now. The 'maven type' job is too abstract for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new job.
2. In Source Management choose Subversion, specify your repo and credentials.
3. Add a new build step - maven build, specify your maven goals ('clean install').

Comment: But I still need to call 'svn update' to update existing code and only after that call maven

Comment: jenkins will checkout the latest version from specified branch. also, you could make it start job on commit.

Comment: yea, I understand that. But I have local repo (all commits that we make go to other server) and this is just downloaded branche. To receive last version of code I have to update existing code. That's why for now I have batch file where there are 'svn update' and 'mvn clean install' commands

Comment: Why can't Jenkins do the checkout? If you're using SVN, run `svnserve` on your machine, so the Jenkins server has access to your repo or run Jenkins locally and let it use `file:///` to access the repo. Jenkins should not be using your working copy. It's a bad practice to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is a CI(contiounus integration) server. It can be used to generate scheduled builds of ant or maven based projects. It can also start building projects by some triggering event such as a commit to SCM (git, svn, mercurial,...)connected to  it. You really have to read its documentation to get a better understanding. It has nice tutorials.