# maven with svn and jenkins

Tags: maven, svn

The repo is already created and i get access to it to perform operaions on my project svn repo.
i would like to use the maven as build tool. and jenkins for continuous integration.
and my questions are:

1. where can i add additional users/give permissions whether in conf/passwd file or i can add in visual svn server managemnnt console.

2.i need to create a new maven project or it may already created by someone?

3. If i want to create a new maven project what are the things i need to do??

4.finally how can i start my project from starting. please tell me the procedure i should follow to work with svn and maven. thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create job in jenkins with calling svn and maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149787/create-job-in-jenkins-with-calling-svn-and-maven)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have a svn repository in the $basedir/conf/password file you can add permissions for a user, provided that your repository access is controlled by a svn password file.  HTTP protocol and / or HTTPS are typically configured via http authorization methods.
2. Creating a maven project is all about writing a `pom.xml` file.  If you can find one, it was already created by someone else.  If you cannot find one, you can write one yourself.  Keep in mind that a maven project is more than just the pom.xml file, it also conforms to the maven standard directory layout (and more, but that should get you started).
3. If you want to create a new maven project, you need an empty directory and to write a pom.xml file.  Depending on the details of what is in the pom.xml file, you might need to also create `src/main/java`, `src/main/resources`, `src/site`, `src/test/java`, and `src/test/resources` directories (and perhaps others).  Note that having a maven project doesn't mean it is under source code control.  If you want that, you might also have to configure a new svn repository (the command is `svnadmin repo create <path>`.
4. There is no single "to start" starting procedure.  The best way to go about it is to gather requirements, document them, figure out a few use cases in detail, write up test plans for those use cases, develop automated tests for those scenarios, write code to make the tests pass, and refine the tests and code in a continuing cycle.  However, many paths lead to the end result (just some are easier to maintain, others easier to get an initial release, etc).

Comment: Next time, please only ask one question per stackoverflow question.

Comment: @chandra archetype:generate will copy out a pom.xml file configured with the archetype system.  The dependencies that pom.xml file references will be copies of whatever archetype template you started with.  Sometimes that is enough, sometimes you will need to add more.  Either way, those dependencies will not be downloaded and used by your project until you call your first `maven compile` (or other default-build-path target.  Then maven will resolve the pom.xml dependencies and download them to your `.m2` repository directory.

Comment: 1. developers checkin into svn repo(where maven pro existed) 2. check out maven pro to locql machine 3.build 4.deployments is the procedure it will be??? can u please temme the exact work procedure when working with maven and svn together

Comment: @chandra You create the svn repo.  You checkout, setup the basic "tags/trunk/branches" directories, and check them in.  Then you erase the repo and check out the "trunk" branch.  Then you add in your pom.xml file, and the maven directories.  Then you check in.  Now you will have a svn repo ready for maven development.  To "deploy" you need to also set up a "maven binary repository" and configure you project to "deploy" to that repository.   Then you use the repository as a source to read from when you need the binaries in a machine.

Comment: thanks but little bit confusing. let me get clear please. 1.create a new maven project in local machine so now pom.xml & src are created 3.check out the trunk code(svn repo) into maven src folder 4.mvn package to build so in Target the built package will be stored. am i right edwin.am i moving forward in right direction?

Comment: @chandra Try it a few times on repositories you will not use.  You are trying to be a "perfect" artist before you have touched the paint brushes.  Everything comes from practice, and if you mess up, that's called a "opportunity to learn".  Mistakes are how we learn, so don't try to avoid them (unless you want to avoid the learning too).

Comment: @chandra So, get a copy of `svnadmin` and make a few repositories on your local machine.  Then use the `file:///` url to check in and out of it to a different directory.  Hand write a `pom.xml` file and see if you can put it in where you want it.  Finally, check it out into an IDE.  If it works, it works (and you'll know more about it than you can find out by just asking).